# Convert decimal to string

Tags: c#

While converting decimal value 0.00005 to string the code converts it to 5E-05. 
The value 0.00005 is from a DataTable row. 
How do I restrict converting the same to keep it 0.00005 instead of 5E-05?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use the [decimal.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#overloads) override to specify a formatting.

```
 decimal val = 0.00005 ;
 string str = amount.ToString("0.00");
```

> Or, it cannot be done on one line.

```
decimal val = 0.00005 ;
string str = amount.ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", String.Empty);
```

> When using String.Format.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", amount);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `decimal` doesn't track any notional format internally - it is just the value (although it does include the precision, which can be different for values that evaluate as equal). You should specify the format explicitly when converting to a string; "general" is the shorter of "exponential" and "fixed-point", so you probably want to use "fixed-point" always; as such: try `value.ToString("F{some size}")` - for example `"F5"`. Alternatively: use a [custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) to indicate the places you want explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
((decimal)(0.00005 )).ToString()
```

Comment: FYI If you want a decimal literal just put a M at the end `0.00005M.ToString()`

Comment: No need to cast a decimal as decimal